# Active Directory - Identical Forward Lookup Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, dns-zone

If my FQDN is ad.domain.com . Can i create a new forward lookup zone named domain.com to create subdomains like www. or mail. ? Or would that basically destroy my AD because the DNS Server tries to resolve ad. as a subdomain to the lookup zone domain.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ad.domain.com` and `domain.com` aren't identical forward lookup zones. What's more, `ad.domain.com` wouldn't be a sub-domain of `domain.com` unless it were actually configured/created as a sub-domain of `domain.com`.

So, no this won't break your AD DNS.

Comment: Thanks! Do i have to configure a delegation in domain.com pointing to ad.domain.com ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can. That kind of arrangement is known as Split DNS.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS